# Initialize Vectors to Contain 13 Elements

Tags: c++, managed-c++

i am trying to initialize vectors to contain 13 elements each in class constructor.

Since in the following case compiler gives " syntax error : 'constant' " .

```
#include <vector>
using namespace System;  
public ref class MyClass {
public :
      vector<int> vector1D(13) ;     //  Syntax error : 'constant'
      vector<vector<int>> vector2D(13,vector<int>(13)) ;
```

};

Then how can the vector be initialized to contain 13 elements in constructor ?

Answer (score 1):

Non-static members have to be initialised in the constructor definition, not the member declaration:

```
class MyClass {
public :
      vector<int> vector1D;
      vector<vector<int>> vector2D;

      MyClass() : 
          vector1D(13),
          vector2D(13,vector<int>(13))
      {}
};
```

Comment: in this case it may not be the suitable syntax. Compiler gives a new error : MyClass : mixed types are not supported

Comment: @eliz: I'm guessing that's something to do with Managed C++, and I don't know anything about that. This is how you'd initialise them in standard C++; according to Dialecticus' answer, you might need to use some weird non-standard array type instead of `vector`.

Comment: anyway i will change the class not to use array

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
public :
    vector<int> vector1D;
    vector< vector<int> > vector2D;

    MyClass()
    {
        vector1D = vector<int>(13);
        vector2D = vector< vector<int> > (13, vector<int>(13));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reserve room for 13 elements in the constructor. Use [vector::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/) for that.

Comment: You can initialise it to contain 13 elements in the constructor, though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, if you know at construction time what the 13 elements are. I don't see that in the OP's code.

Comment: The OP's code is trying to initialise it with 13 value-initialised values, using the constructor that does exactly that. The only problem is that it needs to be done in the constructor definition, not the member declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If `MyClass` is managed class then it cannot have unmanaged members.

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#include <vector>

using namespace System;

public ref class MyClass {
public :
    cli::array<int>^ vector1D;
    cli::array<cli::array<int>^>^ vector2D;
    MyClass()
    {
        Array::Resize(vector1D, 13);
        Array::Resize(vector2D, 13);

        for each (cli::array<int>^ item in vector2D)
            Array::Resize(item, 13);
    }
};
```

Comment: Array is ok but it must be vector in here

Comment: Then `MyClass` cannot be `ref`.